# How do I get second select option to show up based on first select option

Tags: javascript, select

I'm trying to create dropdown lists based on previous dropdown list selections.  I've see a few JQuery answers, but I'm pretty sure this is straight forward enough to not need all the JQuery plugin overhead to pull off, plus I don't have time to learn additional syntax (I know some of you will say that I don't have time NOT to, but this is where I'm at now).

Here's my code so far:

```js
var select = document.getElementById('division');
var dept = document.getElementById('dept').value;
var x = Array("");
var a = Array("A20", "A30", "A40", "A50");
var b = Array("B20", "B30", "B40", "B50");

function divSelect(){
 if(dept === ""){
  for(var i = 0; i< x.length; ++i) {
   select[select.length] = new Option(x[i],x[i]);
  }
 } else if(dept === "A"){
  for(var i = 0; i< a.length; ++i) {
   select[select.length] = new Option(a[i],a[i]);
  }
 } else if(dept === "B"){
  for(var i = 0; i< b.length; ++i) {
   select[select.length] = new Option(b[i],b[i]);
  }  
 } 
}
```

```html
  <select id="dept" onchange='divSelect()'>
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value="A">A</option>
 <option value="B">B</option>
 <option value="E">E</option>
 <option value="M">M</option>
 <option value="R">R</option>
 <option value="V">V</option>
</select>

<select id='division'>
 <option></option> 
</select>
```

Need some help with the function that will select the correct array to display in the second select list.  I also want to clear the second select list every time a new "dept" is selected from the first list.

Thought I could use select.removeAllRanges(); right before the for loop to do this but I get an error.

Appreciate any help you all can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the variable declaration inside the `divSelect()` function. Then only the variables get initialized every time you click on the dropdown.

Also add `select.options.length = 0;` to clear the previous values in the `division` dropdown every time you select a new `dept`.

```js
function divSelect(){

var select = document.getElementById('division');
var dept = document.getElementById('dept').value;
var x = Array("");
var a = Array("A20", "A30", "A40", "A50");
var b = Array("B20", "B30", "B40", "B50");

select.options.length = 0;

 if(dept === ""){
  for(var i = 0; i< x.length; ++i) {
   select[select.length] = new Option(x[i],x[i]);
  }
 } else if(dept === "A"){
  for(var i = 0; i< a.length; ++i) {
   select[select.length] = new Option(a[i],a[i]);
  }
 } else if(dept === "B"){
  for(var i = 0; i< b.length; ++i) {
   select[select.length] = new Option(b[i],b[i]);
  }  
 } 
}
```

```html
  <select id="dept" onchange='divSelect()'>
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value="A">A</option>
 <option value="B">B</option>
 <option value="E">E</option>
 <option value="M">M</option>
 <option value="R">R</option>
 <option value="V">V</option>
</select>

<select id='division'>
 <option></option> 
</select>
```

Comment: Perfect.  Just what I needed.  Appreciate the quick and straight forward answer.

Comment: Glad I could help :')

Answer (score 2):

Please try like this, You can empty the select options using `empty();` method like this `$('#division').empty();`

```js
function divSelect()
{
    var select = document.getElementById('division');
    var dept = document.getElementById('dept').value;
    var x = Array("");
    var a = Array("A20", "A30", "A40", "A50");
    var b = Array("B20", "B30", "B40", "B50");

    if(dept === ""){
         $('#division').empty();
         $.each(x, function(val, text) {
                  $('#division').append( new Option(text,val) );
         });
    } else if(dept === "A"){
         $('#division').empty();
           $.each(a, function(val, text) {
                  $('#division').append( new Option(text,val) );
            });
    } else if(dept === "B"){
         $('#division').empty();
         $.each(b, function(val, text) {
                  $('#division').append( new Option(text,val) );
         });     
    }   
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <select id="dept" onchange='divSelect()'>
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
    <option value="M">M</option>
    <option value="R">R</option>
    <option value="V">V</option>
</select>

<select id='division'>
    <option></option> 
</select>
```